# Moving files not accessed for a long time

Tags: windows, batch-file, filesystems

I would like to move files that have not been accessed for a long time. For instance: if I do not access some file by 7 days, it move to `old` sub-folder.

```
file1.txt    1 days         <keep>
file2.txt    2 days         <keep>
file3.txt    4 days         <keep>
file4.txt    7 days         <move to old>
file5.txt    10 days        <move to old>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better use robocopy command

```
set _old=c:\old
     MD %_old%
     ROBOCOPY "C:\folder" %_old% /move /minlad:7
```

Comment: This grabs files with a last _modified_ date older than 7 days. It doesn't address access date at all.

Comment: No problem, I replaced `minage` by `minlad` that does that. :)

Comment: I changed My post sorry